# Create Connected object in GraphQL via Mutation

Tags: react-native, graphql, aws-appsync

What is the best practice to create an object via mutation connected to another object.

Using the following schema:

```
type Question @model {
  id: ID!
  text: String!
  answers: [Answer] @connection(name: "QuestionAnswers")
}
type Answer @model {
  id: ID!
  text: String!
  question: Question @connection(name: "QuestionAnswers")
}
```

The following (and variants of it) fail:

```
mutation CreateAnswer {
  createAnswer(input: {
    text:"Yes",
    question: {
      id: "9d38c759-6b64-4c1f-9e0e-d3b95a72b3a8"
    }
  }) 
    {
        id
    }
  }
```

Serverside code:

```
mutation CreateAnswer($input: CreateAnswerInput!) {
  createAnswer(input: $input) {
    id
    text
    question {
      id
      text
      answers {
        nextToken
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the above, receiving the following error:

> "Validation error of type WrongType: argument 'input' with value
>   'ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='text',
>   value=StringValue{value='3'}}, ObjectField{name='question',
>   value=ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='id',
>   value=StringValue{value='9d38c759-6b64-4c1f-9e0e-d3b95a72b3a8'}}]}}]}'
>   contains a field not in 'CreateAnswerInput': 'question' @
>   'createAnswer'"

Comment: That query seems syntactically valid to me.  Do you have the actual error message, the GraphQL schema, or any of the matching server-side code that goes with it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Have added the schema, serverside code and error above.

Comment: What's `input CreateAnswerInput` look like?

Comment: Its: {
    text:"Yes",
    question: {
      id: "9d38c759-6b64-4c1f-9e0e-d3b95a72b3a8"
    }
  } Unless I am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that this may be a naming convention in AppSync. The below worked for me:

```
mutation createAnswer {
  createAnswer (input: {
    text: "5"
    answerQuestionId: "9d38c759-6b64-4c1f-9e0e-d3b95a72b3a8"
  }) {
    id
  }
```

Adding *answer* to `QuestionId` was what was needed.